# Is it possible getting the no of subscribers in Crossbar.io router

Tags: crossbar, wamp-protocol

I am using Crossbar (WAMP Protocol) router for my node.js application.As router is  independent to our application I am not able to do the below operations with Crossbar. Is there any official API available to achieve the below functionality.

1. **Disconnection notification of a subscriber for a specific topic?**
2. **List of subscribers for a specific topic?**
3. **New subscription notification for a specific topic when a new 
   subscriber subscribes it.**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

First, yes, a WAMP router should be looked at as a black-box, and hence no app code should dive into router internals.

But there are scenarios (like yours), where an app has a legitimate need to access meta information from the router.

WAMP has so-called *meta events* and *meta procedures* for this. E.g. [here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Session-Metaevents/) is how [Crossbar.io](http://crossbar.io/) exposes session information via meta-events.

The information you are after seem all be related to "subscribers". In the WAMP spec:

- [Subscriber Meta Events](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/advanced.md#subscriber-meta-events)
- [Subscriber List](https://github.com/tavendo/WAMP/blob/master/spec/advanced.md#subscriber-list)

These are not yet (2015/01) implemented in Crossbar.io, but we'll have it.